# Are Neural Networks with a softmax output layer considered Probabilistic Classifiers?

Tags: neural-networks

For example, is ResNet for image classification a type of Probabilistic Classifier when we take into account the softmax at the end of the network as part of the network? My intuition points in that direction, given that it estimates the probability of an image belonging to each possible class, and then takes the class with the highest probability.

Comment: What is your definition of a probabilistic classifier?

Comment: I would define as: A probabilistic classifier is a type of classifier that, in order to determine the class of a given sample, calculates the probability of the sample belonging to each  possible class and then assigns the sample to that class with the highest probability.

Answer (score 2):

The softmax output of a neural network classifier can be considered a probabilistic classification, however the probabilities will often not be well calibrated. Well calibrated means that the estimated probability matches our confidence in the prediction - in other words, the classifier is well calibrated it makes the correct prediction 80% of the time it predicts class A with 80% probability (and similarly for all other probabilities).

If calibrated probabilities are required then a post-classification calibration step can be used. This essentially rescales the softmax output to adjust the probabilities to more closely match the expected distribution.

Reference: [How and When to Use a Calibrated Classification Model with scikit-learn](https://machinelearningmastery.com/calibrated-classification-model-in-scikit-learn/) by Jason Brownlee.